# Pygame wall sprite collision

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision, roguelike

I am making a roguelike game, but I am beginner when it comes to coding. I already have my character moving, my wall and floor sprites, but there is some error in my code that allows the character to move through walls.

I used the `block_path` to choose between the floor and wall tile and I tried to use it then to recognize the wall but it didn't really work.

Next, you can see my code:

```
screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 600
mapHeight = 30
mapWidth = 30
cellWidth = 32
cellHeight = 32

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('model/r1.png'), pygame.image.load('model/r2.png'), pygame.image.load('model/r3.png'), pygame.image.load('model/r4.png'), pygame.image.load('model/r5.png'), pygame.image.load('model/r6.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('model/l1.png'), pygame.image.load('model/l2.png'), pygame.image.load('model/l3.png'), pygame.image.load('model/l4.png'), pygame.image.load('model/l5.png'), pygame.image.load('model/l6.png')]
walkUp = [pygame.image.load('model/u1.png'), pygame.image.load('model/u2.png'), pygame.image.load('model/u3.png'), pygame.image.load('model/u4.png'), pygame.image.load('model/u5.png'), pygame.image.load('model/u6.png')]
Floor = pygame.image.load("map/floor.jpg")
wallRight = pygame.image.load("map/rightwall.png")
```

`

```
class struc_Tile():
    def __init__(self,block_path):
        self.block_path = block_path`

class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.walkCount = 0


    def draw(self,screen):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            self.walkCount = 0

        elif self.left:
            screen.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            screen.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.up:
            screen.blit(walkUp[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.down:
            screen.blit(walkDown[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            screen.blit(Standing[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount = 0

    def move(self,dx,dy):
        if gamemap[self.x + dx][self.y + dy].block_path == False:
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy

def createmap():
    newmap = [[struc_Tile(False) for y in range(0,mapHeight)] for x in range (0,mapWidth) ]
    newmap[10][10].block_path = True
    newmap[10][15].block_path = True

    return newmap
        def drawmap(maptodraw):

    for x in range(0,mapWidth):
        for y in range(0,mapHeight):
            if maptodraw[x][y].block_path == True:
                screen.blit(wallRight, (x*cellWidth, y*cellHeight))
            else:
                screen.blit(Floor, (x*cellWidth, y*cellHeight)
def redrawgamewindow():
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
drawmap(gamemap)
character.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
gamemap = createmap()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
character = player(0, 0, 32,32)

run = True
while run:
clock.tick(18)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

        run = False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and character.x > character.vel:
    character.x -= character.vel
    character.left = True
    character.right = False
    character.up = False
    character.down = False
    character.standing = False

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and character.x < 800 -character.width - character.vel:
    character.x += character.vel
    character.left = False
    character.right = True
    character.up = False
    character.down = False
    character.standing = False

elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and character.y > character.vel:
    character.y -= character.vel
    character.left = False
    character.right = False
    character.up = True
    character.down = False
    character.standing = False
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and character.y < 600 - character.height - character.vel:
    character.y += character.vel
    character.left = False
    character.right = False
    character.up = False
    character.down = True
    character.standing = False
else:
    character.right = False
    character.left = False
    character.up = False
    character.down = False
    character.standing = True

redrawgamewindow()
```

Comment: In `createmap()` you're only blocking 2 tiles, so the only time you're path would possibly be blocked is if you're trying to move over one of those 2 tiles.

Comment: It's also pretty difficult to reproduce what's going on with your code without seeing some more of it.

Comment: I added the rest of my code. I tried moving over those 2 tiles and it wasn't blocked.

Comment: What are `mapHeight` and `mapWidth` set to? You never have those set in your example.

Comment: My intention is that they represent the size of the map ( number of tiles), for example my map 30x30 tile map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your `createmap()` function to something like this will create a 5 pixel buffer on the boreder of your map. The reason I made it 5 pixels is because that's what your character movement is.

I would suggest putting in some actual character collision to test whether you're out of bounds regardless of speed though.

EDIT: I've included the full code since the changes I've made are easier to understand if I show them.

I've changed your image lists to a dict of list since they're easier to call that way. The grid you asked for is 30x30. Since you showed a 32x32 cell width I changed the map to 960 x 960.

I've extended your move method to check for collision to see if it can move before it does. I've also removed your `redraw()` function since it was easier to just move your redraw down. If you wish, you can add it back in but for this example, I removed it.

```
import pygame

# Based on the paths in your image
# This should work for your image paths
image = pygame.image.load('model/standing1.png')
Standing = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))
image = pygame.image.load('map/floor.jpg')
Floor = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))
image = pygame.image.load('map/rightwall.png')
wallRight = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))

walkLeft = []
walkRight = []
walkUp = []
walkDown = []

for i in range(1, 19):
    image = pygame.image.load('model/r' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/l' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkLeft.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/u' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkUp.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/d' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkDown.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

class struc_Tile():
    def __init__(self, block_path):
        self.block_path = block_path

class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.walkCount = 0

        # do something like this with your images
        # if you keep your lists in a dict you can avoid
        # all your boolean direction variables and 
        # the lengthy if else statement
        self.images = {}
        self.images['walkleft'] = walkLeft[:]
        self.images['walkright'] = walkRight[:]
        self.images['walkup'] = walkUp[:]
        self.images['walkdown'] = walkDown[:]


    def draw(self, screen, direction):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            self.walkCount = 0

        # since standing is not in your dict check for that first
        if direction == 'standing':
            screen.blit(Standing, (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            screen.blit(self.images[direction][self.walkCount], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1


    def can_move(self, dx, dy):
        # with the buffer created around the border of the map
        # you shouldn't have issues with
        # index out of bounds exceptions
        # EDIT: added better collision
        new_x = self.x + dx
        new_y = self.y + dy
        if gamemap[new_x][new_y].block_path == False:
            if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y].block_path == False:
                if gamemap[new_x][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                    if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                        self.x += dx
                        self.y += dy
                        return True

def createmap():
    newmap = [[struc_Tile(False) for y in range(0, mapHeight)] for x in range (0,mapWidth)]

    # give our upper/left borders a cell width buffer
    # and our bottom/right borders a 2 cell width buffer
    # since blit uses the upper left corner this should account
    # for the sprite width
    # EDIT: Fixed this to accommodate the better collision
    for x in range(0, mapWidth):
        for y in range (0, mapHeight):
            if y < 32 or y + cellWidth >= mapHeight:
                newmap[x][y].block_path = True
            elif x < 32 or x + cellWidth >= mapWidth:
                newmap[x][y].block_path = True


    return newmap

def drawmap(maptodraw):
    # only blit at cellwidth and height intervals
    for x in range(0, mapWidth, cellWidth):
        for y in range(0, mapHeight, cellHeight):
            if maptodraw[x][y].block_path == True:
                screen.blit(wallRight, (x, y))
            else:
                screen.blit(Floor, (x, y))

# Added this function which lets you block or unblock a cell
# simply call like gamemap = block_element(5, 10, gamemap)
# this will block the 6th cell on the x axis and 11th on the y axis
# to unblock a cell call it with block=False
def block_element(x, y, maptoblock, block=True):
    x_cells = int(mapWidth / cellWidth)
    y_cells = int(mapHeight / cellHeight)

    start_x = int(x * cellWidth)
    start_y = int(y * cellHeight)

    end_x = start_x + cellWidth
    end_y = start_y + cellHeight

    print(start_x, end_x)

    if x >= 0 and x < x_cells:
        if y >= 0 and y < y_cells:
            for x in range(start_x, end_x):
                for y in range(start_y, end_y):
                    maptoblock[x][y].block_path = block

    return maptoblock   

pygame.init()

mapHeight = 960
mapWidth = 960

cellWidth = 32
cellHeight = 32

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapWidth, mapHeight))

gamemap = createmap()
# blocking/unblocking example
gamemap = block_element(5, 10, gamemap)
gamemap = block_element(0, 8, gamemap, block=False)
gamemap = block_element(0, 9, gamemap, block=False)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
character = player(64, 64, 32, 32)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(18)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            run = False
    # I just used fill since I didn't have a bg image handy
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    drawmap(gamemap)

    # handle the keypresses
    # first check if the character can move that much
    # then draw the movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and character.can_move(0 - character.vel, 0):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkleft')
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and character.can_move(character.vel, 0):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkright')
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and character.can_move(0, 0 - character.vel):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkup')
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and character.can_move(0, character.vel):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkdown')
    else:
        character.draw(screen, 'standing')
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/57291d59ebd8fa48a7b1a93303d42300                                                         This is what I got when I made the change, I never had a problem with the borders of my map, because character.x < 800 -character.width - character.vel, takes care of it. My only problem is with making the wall tiles block my character. I should probably try to find a different way of making my map.

Comment: I spent two hours trying to use the code you gave, but somehow I managed to not make it work. Everytime I press a key to move it crashes, for example if I press right key it calls this 2 lines "character.draw(screen, 'walkright')" and             screen.blit(self.images[direction][self.walkCount], (self.x,self.y))  This is how I inserted my sprites https://gyazo.com/cccd92e3c04973b3ff16d4de7a71040b                                               and I didn't touch nothing else idk if I have to touch the dictionary inside class player. One last question how can I insert walls at chosen coordinate

Comment: I see your problem but I'm on the way home right now. I'll address it when I get home.

Comment: @JoseVaz I updated my example with the paths you provided for your images. If you can't get it working in 15 minutes or so, let me know, and we'll work through it.

Comment: That's perfect, you saved me. Now I just need to figure out how to make walls in the middle of the map, but that shouldn't be too hard. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem @JoseVaz. I added a function that allows you to block or unblock any cell you choose in your 30x30 grid.